# Telerik MVC EditorTemplate Model is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using a Telerik MVC grid to let the users manage the reports in the system.
I built an EditorTemplate with some fields in it and with an uploader from Telerik.

I want to pass the ReportId to the uploader method so that it knows the report record to which the file belongs.

```
@model MyMvcApp.Models.ReportModel

@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.ReportID)

@Html.HiddenFor(t=> t.ReportID)

@(Html.Telerik().Upload()
          .Name("attachments")
          .Multiple(false)
          .Async(async => async.Save("Save", "Report", 
                            new { Id = Model.ReportID })
          .AutoUpload(true)
))
```

However, the `Model.RaportId` returns an empty GUID.

Also, the `@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.ReportID)` doesn't work properly.

But the `@Html.HiddenFor(t=> t.ReportID)` works just fine when I inspect the page.

I know that Telerik is building a dummy model when creating the editor template. But what can be done?

- Use javascript to populate a ViewBag variable and use that in the save method?
- Call the model in a different way?

All in all, I have now changed to using separate views for create/update, but I'd like to build this into the grid. The experience would be better.

Comment: Are there any DataAnnotations on your ReportId field like this ? [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]

Comment: No. The problem has to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to leverage the [`OnUpload` method from Telerik MVC's Client API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-client-api-and-events.html).

This method gives you access to the data before the upload request is sent.  So, you have a place to debug the upload data, and if it is not correct then you can manipulate it (e.g. add the correct ReportID parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and started searching. According to telerik, the [Display templates are not supported in ajax edit mode](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/clajax-databinding-client-editing.aspx#1906385) . I think it makes sense as the edit mode pops up almost instantaneously. You will need to use the grid's OnEdit event.

I am using a disabled text box for now like the following.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReportId, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```